# How to convert the time of a day in number of seconds given the following conditions

Tags: java

Given the time of a day in number of seconds, convert it into time in hhmmss format. Note that the time is past noon, and hence the hours will never be less than 12.

Sample Input #1
(86399)

Sample Output #1
235959

**MyApproach:**

I want to ask how the time is converted

given the time in seconds
86399

According to what I understood I converted this time like

```
($86399$/$3600$)=23 hrs 

($86399$/$60$)=1439minutes

 $86399$=$87861$seconds
```

I think I am doing wrong and I don't know why?
Can Anyone guide how to convert this time?

@Edit

Below is my code:

```
public class SecondsToTime 
{
 public static void main(String args[]) 
 {
    SecondsToTime obj = new SecondsToTime();
    int result = obj.toTime(86399);
    System.out.println(result);
 }

 public int toTime(int seconds)
 {
     int a=n/$3600$=23 hrs //if n=86399

     int b=n/$60$=1439minutes   //if n=86399

     int c=n=$87861$seconds     //if n=86399

     return a+b+c;


 }  
}
```

Comment: Please, provide your java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the first step, you're just missing the second one. To get the number of minutes past the hour:

```
(input / 60) % 60
```

In other words:

```
(timeOfDayInSeconds / secondsPerMinute) % minutesPerHour
```

Comment: To calculate number of  seconds.We do  input % 60 In other words  (timeOfDayInSeconds% seconds Per minute Is this right?

Comment: A practical application of this would be converting Unix time to something human-readable. It's expressed as the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, and in Java, you can get it via `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: Why we are doing %. I am not getting any Logical Sense.Though I am getting Ans.

Comment: '%' is the *modulo* operator. It returns the remainder from integer division.